# Install CakePHP's DebugKit with composer

Tags: debugging, cakephp, installation, composer-php

I have installed CakePHP manually (not by composer) and I think it's the recommended way, as it is not mentioned in CakePHP site to use composer and there is a just download link. After installing it, I wanted to install the DebugKit. Should I install the DebugKit manually because I installed the CakePHP manually? Or it's totally unrelated?

First of all, I'm totally new to composer! But I tried the composer-way instructions (because it seems the recommended way) and added the following lines to CakePHP composer.json:

```
"require": {
    "cakephp/debug_kit": "2.2.*"
}
```

And Although not mentioned, then I executed "composer install" in the CakePHP install folder, because just adding these lines did not do anything! But then I had two root folders for plugin, i.e. *plugin* and *plugins*, and for vendor, i.e. *vendor* and *vendors*. The newly created vendor folder had some folders (other than DebugKit). And the DebugKit is now under *plugin* root folder not *app/plugin*.

So why are these newly created vendor and plugin folder if there exist their plural ones (vendors and plugins)?

If I installed the DebugKit manually I didn't have vendor subfolders contents (bin composer phpunit symfony/yaml autoload.php)! so if these files are needed why they did not exist before and if not why are there?

If I should totally ignore composer.json in manual installation, why is it there? And with some content differently from the suggested one for installing CakePHP with composer!?

Answer (score 0):

If you are installing cakePHP 3.0 then the only way is with composer.

Take a look at

https://github.com/cakephp/app

Comment: oh no! you should revise your answer! Following your link, I see in 3.x source code, and it hasn't Debug Kit.

Comment: Huh? What do you mean?

Comment: I do not use CakePHP 3.0 as it is not stable yet. Do you mean if I install CakePHP 2.5 with composer, I will have a totaly different layout? and I should simply ignore the composer.json in downloaded way of installation, and I can delete it?